# Display input value in a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an input field and a button next to it, what i want to do is whatever i type in the input field then click on the button next to it, the result gets displayed in another button, here is what i tried so far:

```js
function add_keyword() {
  var keyword_value = (document.getElementById("keyword").value);
  var result = keyword_value;

  document.getElementById("btnresult").value = result;
}
```

```css
#btnresult{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="clickbtn" value="Add Keyword" onclick="add_keyword()">Add</button>

<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="keyword" name="keywordbox"/>
</div>

<button type="button" id="btnresult" class="btn btn-default">input value should be here</button>
```

Comment: you are css needs to be updated on button click - to block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/p2LoLcv3/

I *think* this is what you are describing...

Some simplified markup

```
<div class="parent">
  <input type='button' value='Add' rel='action' /><br>
  <input type='text' rel='text-input' />
</div>

<ul class='button-list' rel='button-list'>
  <!-- you need to put the buttons somewhere, right? -->
</ul>
```

jQuery was one of the tags, so I used it

```
// just caching some thing that will be reused (I like using rel)
var $parent = $('.parent'); // whatever - to keep some scope
var $addButton = $parent.find('[rel="action"]');
var $textInput = $parent.find('[rel="text-input"]');

var $buttonList = $('[rel="button-list"]');

$addButton.on('click', function() { // on click...
  var currentInputValue = $textInput.val(); // get the value from input...
  $buttonList.append('<li><button>' + currentInputValue + '</button></li>'); // append a new button...
  $textInput.val(''); // clear input
});
```

Comment: Why not post your code here as a Stack Snippet instead of using jsfiddle?

Comment: If it's a timeless question - and OP has learned how to ask questions well, I might use a Stack Snippet - but otherwise, I think it's a better way to lead by example. You can't easily fork the snippets. I'll give them another chance. What is your argument for them? : ) - also - I use stylus - a lot.

Comment: The argument is to keep SO self-contained, rather than depending on external sites.

Comment: Yeah - well, they are newer. - also, they don't work for everything. I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: @Barmar - OK... I checkout out the native snippets with an open mind. Not going to use them. The are a huge pain to edit - or at least the whole experience is unintuitive and annoying. If you have some magical resource I'm missing... point the way.

Comment: They're about 75% the same as jsfiddle, IMO. And the embedded console is a nice addition that jsfiddle doesn't have.

Comment: I've been struggling with that debate myself. To me the Stack Snippet looks cluttered in the response... the editor looks nice (like jsFiddle) but only the creator gets to view it that way, others can't edit/fork, and external resources are included inline in the HTML code, cluttering things up.

Comment: If you have 10 posts with 40 lines of code - all using snippets - the pages pretty terrible to use. If you need to make one little change - can you even get the editor open again? No forking... no sharing again on other sites... or referencing in another post. I would still need to answer the question with jsFiddle - until I was sure it answered the question... then I could put the final in a SS... but I shouldn't even be answering questions on here in the first place. : / If people could keep their examples minimal - maybe... but they do not - and display the same html again...

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, you have to *unhide* the button you've hidden in the first place, and not set a value for a button, but rather the innerHTML property. Since a button doesn't hold a value, but displays the content between the tags as text.

I've commented my changes:

```js
function add_keyword() {
    var keyword_value = (document.getElementById("keyword").value);
    var result = keyword_value;
    // Changed from .value to .innerHTML
    document.getElementById("btnresult").innerHTML = result;
    // Changed style from to 'block'
    document.getElementById("btnresult").style.display = "block"
}
```

```css
#btnresult{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="clickbtn" value="Add Keyword" onclick="add_keyword()">Add</button>
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="keyword" name="keywordbox"/>
</div>
<button type="button" id="btnresult" class="btn btn-default">input value should be here</button>
```

In addition, there are several aspects of your code that could use improvement, I described them below:

```
function add_keyword() {
    // No need for parentheses around the document.getElement function.
    var keyword_value = document.getElementById("keyword").value;
    // There's no need to place the value in a new variable, it is useful to place the element you wish to replace in a variable, since we'll be re-using it's instance.
    var btn = document.getElementById("btnresult");
    btn.innerHTML = keyword_value;
    btn.style.display = "block"
}
```

**EDIT**: Since OP's goal was to create a new button with the content, this is an updated version that generates a new button for every new input.

```js
function add_keyword() {
    var keyword_value = document.getElementById("keyword").value;
    // Create a new button element.
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    // Set it's content to the keyword from the input.
    btn.innerHTML = keyword_value
    // Append it to the body.
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="clickbtn" value="Add Keyword" onclick="add_keyword()">Add</button>
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="keyword" name="keywordbox"/>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much i get it now! but one more thing, i want different buttons to get displayed once i change the value then i click on the add again, how can i do it?

Comment: Do you mean to have a new button added based on a new 'add', or do you wish to replace the content of the first button?

Comment: Done @stephjhonny :).